# Disable auto indexing of mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

I understand MySQL is automatically placing an index on every table's primary and foreign keys.

However, I would like to personally create my own indices on the foreign keys as I want to execute a query with hibernate showing the difference in time when I execute it with and without indices.

Is there any option in MySQL Workbench to disable it's auto indexing feature?

Comment: To whoever downvoted this: Could you at least explain why you downvote this before doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No** you cannot disable the auto index creation of index on tables. This is a inbuilt feature which is added in MySql.

However if you want you can drop the index like this:

```
DROP INDEX index_name ON tbl_name
```

and then create it again.

From [InnoDB and FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

> "InnoDB requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. (This is in contrast to some older versions, in which indexes
>   had to be created explicitly or the creation of foreign key
>   constraints would fail.) index_name, if given, is used as described
>   previously."

Comment: Aye but aren't these indexnames generated with a random name? (ie no way to do it programatically in hibernate)

Comment: @RobinHellemans:- No you dont have a control over it. However if you drop it and then if you recreate it then you can name it as per your convenience. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, these indexes are always created. Otherwise, every `UPDATE` or `INSERT` that modifies these columns would have to perform a full table scan, to ensure that the primary key is unique and the foreign key has a valid reference.

Regarding foreign keys, the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) says:

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not exist.